# Getting undefined for object properties and unable to get count

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object with 3 properties and each object's property has an object as its value. I am trying to console.log the online property of each object but I get `undefined`. I am also try count the number of online properties set to true but no number is returned. Why do I get undefined and how do I count the online properties set to true?

```
function countOnline(usersObj) {

  let count = 0;
  for (let user in usersObj) {
    console.log(user);
    console.log(user.online);
  }
  return count;

}
const users = {
  Alan: {
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    online: false
  }
}

countOnline(users);
```

Comment: Your function returns `0` because you forgot to increment your `count` variable in the `for...in` loop

Comment: `user` is the property name not the object it contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user` is the key, not the value. Furthermore, you need to increment the `count` each time the online property is true.

```
for (let user in usersObj) {
    console.log(usersObj[user]);
    console.log(userObjs[user].online);
    if(userObjs[user].online)
        ++count;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function countOnline(usersObj) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let user in usersObj) {
    console.log(usersObj[user]);
    console.log(usersObj[user].online);
    if(usersObj[user].online) ++count;
  }
  return count;
}
const users = {
  Alan: {
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    online: false
  }
}
console.log(countOnline(users));
```

Comment: Thanks. that was it.

Comment: @larry8989 No problem.